# Help_Contents not showing in Eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, product

I built an Eclipse product.  When I test the project in Eclipse everything works fine, I can do Help->Help Contents and see the help content my plugin contains.

If I export the product, and start it, everything works except that Help->Help Contents does nothing.  I suspect that I am missing some plugins in my product dependencies.  But I don't see which ?

I added all the org.eclipse.help* and the org.mortbay.jetty.* (since I noticed that when launching the Help Contents from my test in Eclipse, the content is served by jetty).   But still no Help Content window after a product export.

Any idea what is missing in the product to display the Help Content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCPHelpSystem/article.html) it is

- org.eclipse.help.ui
- org.eclipse.help.webapp
- org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty

Another potential problem might be that you simply don't have your help content files in the product export. I would try setting a check mark for the help files in the "binary build" section of your build.properties, but I'm not sure here.

Comment: I just double checked my project, the help content files was in the product (i.e. build.properties has the directory that stores all the help content files in bin.includes section).
Turns out that I was missing the `org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty`.  Now it works just fine.  Thanks.